# Как передать параметр?

Tags: веб-программирование, http

Как передать параметр без использования формы.
Используя ссылку не получится?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы пытаетесь сделать "это что-то" не из десктопного приложения, то вам очень поможет CURL( как для GET, так и для POST запросов ). С $_GET запросами все еще легче. Для этого достаточно передать параметры через адресную строку:

```
http://www.example.com/?param1=1&param2=2
```

После знака вопроса идут параметры запроса. Это, собственно, нетрудно реализовать и в десктопном приложении. Данный URL можно использовать и как ссылку, поэтому ответ на ваш вопрос: Можно!

Comment: Точняк, спасибо)